# PHP - Get number of pages in a Word document

Tags: php, ms-word

Is there a way to count number of pages using PHP for existing Word documents?

I appreciate for the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a library that can read Word docs. I recommend: http://www.phplivedocx.org/ You'll also need the Zend Framework: http://framework.zend.com/

I'm sure there are many more libraries available, but I find this to be the most current and well maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find an appropriate 3rd party library (or write your own) if you are using a Windows server you could look into using a COM interface.

Here is how you would do it with COM... (but I haven't tested it yet)

```
   $wdStatisticPages = 2;
   $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
   $word->Document->Open( "path/to/file.doc" );
   $num_pages = $word->ActiveDocument->ComputeStatistics( $wdStatisticPages );
```

Comment: i have this error: Unable to lookup `Document': Unknown name.

Answer (score 1):

To get meta data properties of doc,docx,ppt and pptx like number of pages, number of slides from PHP i followed the following process and it worked liked charm and iam so happy, below is the process i followed , hope it helps someone

```
Download and configure Apache Tika.
```

once its done you could try executing the following commadn it will give all the meta data about your file

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.docx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.doc
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.pptx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.ppt
```

once tested you can execute this comman in `PHP script`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is difficult to do reliably, because the number of pages in a Word document can depend on what printer driver is installed in the Word application used to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PhpWord from microsoft codeplex ... "http://phpword.codeplex.com/

It will allow you to open and read the word formatted file in PHP and do whatever processing you require.

Comment: Dead software, last release in 2011

Comment: I think it got replaced by this project on GitHub
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Still the PHPWord is not alive. the contributor might be out of reach.