# Get number of pages in a .doc document on linux

Tags: php, ms-word, .doc

With respect to the topic:

[How to get the number of pages in a Word Document on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986067/how-to-get-the-number-of-pages-in-a-word-document-on-linux)

has anyone been successful with *.doc* files (*.docx* are resolved)?

Comment: There was a [question on ask Ubuntu about `.docx` to `.doc` conversion](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161665/how-to-convert-docx-to-doc-with-terminal).  If you could do that, then the answer for `.docx` would suffice.

Comment: Note the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9103304/438971) to the question you quote has an answer for the 97-2003 format `.doc` files following the answer for `.docx`.

Comment: Thank you Orbling, but the accepted answer is unfinished regarding .doc files.

Comment: Annoyingly both the links for the file structure are dead too - so you'll need to find that first before you can write something to do it yourself.

Comment: Maybe a more novel approach - find a Word to PDF converter, then there are various PDF tools that can tell you the number of pages.  Quite slow though that will be.

Comment: I've added comments to the accepted answer on where exactly the page count can be found, with documentation.

Comment: Thank you Orbling, really helpful comment! I am on it...

Answer (score 1):

I made a program in Java executable jar you Download it from below mentioned URL, It will extract page numbers from multiple doc or docx.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/qe1jkdf8807v5y7/Word_Page_Counter.jar

Answer (score -1):

Normally, if you have a .doc open in MS Word or another office application like LibreOffice, there is a status bar at the bottom of the window. At the left side in Libre is the page count, for example: Page 1 of 7 Can't recall if it is exactly the same in Word, but certainly somewhere on that status bar.

Comment: I meant to determine it programmatically... I am aware of what you mentioned although.. Thank you.