# Find out page numbers of Ppt files with php

Tags: php, powerpoint

I want to get the page numbers of ppt files.
My Code:

```
$filename = "aaa.ppt";
$word = new COM("Powerpoint.Application");
$word->PresentationDocument->Open($filename);
$wdStatisticPages = 2; // Value that corresponds to the Page count in the Statistics
echo $word->ActivePresentation->SlideParts->Count($wdStatisticPages);  
$word->ActivePresentation->Close();
$word->Quit();
```

But it gives error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable
>   to lookup `PresentationDocument': Unknown name. '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks Suyog for your efforts.

```
$filename = "aaa.ppt";
$power = new COM("Powerpoint.Application");
$power->visible = True;
$power->Presentations->Open(realpath($filename));
echo $power->ActivePresentation->Slides->Count;  
//$word->ActiveDocument->PrintOut();
$power->ActivePresentation->Close();
$power->Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of issue is due to the following factors.

1. PHP.ini settings
2. File/ Folder Permission
3. allow open is not enabled in the server
4. allowed upload size

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please tell me the solution, i am trying this on my local system not on server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561719/find-out-page-numbers-of-pdf-docx-doc-ppt-pptx-files-with-php

Comment: Sir if you have any working solution then please share, i tried these but they are not working.