# There's a way to count number of words in a .doc?

Tags: php, string, ms-word

I'm trying to figure a way to count the number of words in a `.doc` document with php.
I get nothing at all.

Someone knows a way to do that? I need to count the number of words in a Word document.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Get number of pages in a Word document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156761/php-get-number-of-pages-in-a-word-document)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967828/php-get-a-word-count-from-an-uploaded-microsoft-word-document

Answer (score 1):

Same question with a good answer: [PHP - Get a word count from an uploaded Microsoft Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967828/php-get-a-word-count-from-an-uploaded-microsoft-word-document)

You will need to:

Distinguish the file type

```
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_extn = end(explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'])));

if($file_extn == "doc" || $file_extn == "docx"){
    docx2text();
}elseif($file_extn == "rtf"){
    rtf2text();
}
```

Convert the document to text

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371315/2512934 for doc or docx http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php for rtf

Count the words http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

I hope this helps?